# ytdl: The "url" argument must be of type string. Received type undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm working on a Discord bot using Discord.js and ytdl. However, whenever I type `?play` and my play command is executed, this error is thrown:

> ```js
> (node:15840) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "url" argument must be of type string. Received type undefined
>     at URL.parse(url.js:154:11)
>     at Object.urlParse [as parse] (url.js:148:13)
>     at Object.exports.getURLVideoID (C:\Users\MauSc\Desktop\[MENU DOCS] Bot\node_modules\ytdl-core\lib\util.js:273:22)
>     at Function.exports.validateURL(C:\Users\MauSc\Desktop\[MENU DOCS] Bot\node_modules\ytdl-core\lib\util.js:328:20)
>     at Object.module.exports.run (C:\Users\MauSc\Desktop\[MENU DOCS] Bot\commands\play.js:18:22)
>     at Client.bot.on (C:\Users\MauSc\Desktop\[Menu DOCS] Bot\index.js:51:38)
>     at Client.emit (events.js:198:13)
>     at MessageCreateHandler.handle (C:\Users\MauSc\Desktop\[MENU DOCS] Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\handlers\MessageCreate.js:9:34)
>     at WebSocketPacketManager.handle (C:\Users\MauSc\Desktop\[MENU DOCS] Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\WebSocketPacketManager.js:105:65)
>     at WebSocketConnection.onPacket (C:\Users\MauSc\Desktop\[MENU DOCS] Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:333:35)
> (node:15840) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
> (node:15840) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
> ```

The code is all copied from another bot I made, so I'm not sure why the error suddenly appears.

This is the code:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');
const streamOptions ={
    seek: 0,
    volume: 1
}

const bot = new Discord.Client({disableEveryone: true});

var musicUrls = [];

bot.on("message", async message => {

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
             let url = args[1];
             let voiceChannel = message.guild.channels.find(channel => channel.name === 'Musik Bot');

             if(ytdl.validateURL(url))
             {
                console.log("Valid URL");
                var flag = musicUrls.some(element => element === url);
                if(!flag)
                {
                    musicUrls.push(url);
                    if(voiceChannel != null)
                    {

                        if(voiceChannel.connection)
                        {
                            console.log("Connection exists");
                            const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed();
                            embed.setAuthor(bot.user.username, bot.user.displayAvatarURL);
                            embed.setDescription("Du hast erfolgreich einen Track zu der Playlist hinzugefügt!");
                            message.channel.send(embed);
                        }
                        else {
                            try {
                                const voiceConnection = await voiceChannel.join();
                                await playSong(message.channel, voiceConnection, voiceChannel);
                            }
                            catch(ex)
                            {
                                console.log(ex);
                             }
                         }
                    }

                 }
             }
}
     async function playSong(messageChannel, voiceConnection, voiceChannel)
{
    const stream = ytdl(musicUrls[0], { filter : 'audioonly'});
    const dispatcher = voiceConnection.playStream(stream, streamOptions);

    dispatcher.on('end', () => {
        musicUrls.shift();

        if(musicUrls.length == 0)
            voiceChannel.leave();
        else
        {
            setTimeout(() => {
                 playSong(messageChannel, voiceConnection, voiceChannel);
            }, 1000);
        }
    });
    try {
        if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;
        let commandfile = bot.commands.get(cmd.slice(prefix.length)) || bot.commands.get(bot.aliases.get(cmd.slice(prefix.length)))
        console.log(commandfile);
        if (commandfile) commandfile.run(bot, message, args)
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}},


module.exports.config = {
    name: "play",
    aliases: []
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`args[1]` is undefined when your code is run, which means it was never provided. This causes `url` to also be undefined, and your error is then thrown from ytdl because `validateURL()` expected a string.

Before continuing with the command, ensure that the required argument is present. If not, return an error message. For example...

```js
if (!args[1]) {
  return message.channel.send('You must provide a URL!')
    .catch(console.error);
}
```

Comment: I did add a URL while testing this command. I added the piece of code you added to your answer and this was the result: https://imgur.com/a/qBBbCju

Comment: Okay wait. To define args I need to use "let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");". But then "message" isnt defined. So I would have to add "bot.on("message", async message => {" but then I return to my commandfile.run issue

Comment: Your `args` array should be defined within your original (and only) message event. Make sure that you're passing the parameters to the command correctly when calling the command file's run function. And as said in your previous question, you should export that run function in top-level code; the snippet in your question is incorrect because it'll only export the execution function when the event is emitted. It can't be emitted because (A) you're not using the new client so it won't emit any events at all and (B) the listener is only attached when requiring the file.